# Vba Формулы с неявным диапазоном

Tags: excel, vba, excel-формулы, range, formula

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добрый вечер, знатоки и гуру!
Подскажите , пожалуйста, как в формуле в vba R1C1 сделать диапазон округлениях минимального до последней заполненной строки?
Пробую:

```
ILastrow = Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(ILastrow+3,3).Formula=“=Mround(Min( Range(“D2:D” & ILastrow)),500)”
```

или

```
Cells(ILastrow+3,3).Formula=“=Mround(Min( R[-(ILastrow+3)]C[1]:R[-3]C[1]),500)”
```

Ещё так пробовал:

```
ILastrow = Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp).Row
Range(“D2:D” & ILastrow).Select
Cells(ILastrow+3,3).Formula=“=Mround(Min( ActiveCells. Selection ),500)”
```

Comment: *диапазон округлениях минимального* - расшифруйте. Спрашиваете о  *в vba R1C1*, показываете *Range(“D2:D...”*. Что нужно: вставить формулу или посчитать чего-то без вставки формулы? Или сделать формулу - и не надо VBA?

Comment: Нужно округление от минимума диапазона, в экселе это выглядит так: =ОКРУГЛ(МИН(D2:D30),500). Нужно именно через вба и чтоб последняя ячейка была неявно задана, а через последнюю непустую ячейку

Answer (score 0):

В динамическом диапазоне находим минимальное число и округляем его до 500:

```
Sub Test_()
    Dim ILastrow As Long
    ILastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(ILastrow + 3, 3).Value = Int(Application.Min(Range("D2:D" & ILastrow)) / 500) * 500
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но мы не  должны его округлять, 500 - это число разрядов или точность, в вопросе добавил скрин формулы

Comment: Максимальная длина числового значения в Excel - 16 знаков. Что Вы собираетесь круглять до 500 знака после запятой?!

Comment: я не хочу, просто так принято писать у нас в этой формуле, но я не настаиваю)))

Comment: Да глупость это. Вы указываете функции, что нужно округлять до 500-го знака после запятой. А их (знаков) НЕ МОЖЕТ БОЛЬШЕ 15. В таком случае Вам нужно найти минимальное значение - и все. Выбросьте из формулы округление, лишнее оно. И в показанном коде строку  замените на `Cells(ILastrow + 3, 3).Value = Application.Min(Range("D2:D" & ILastrow))`

Comment: Спасибо большое!)
Так вы имеете ввиду?
Sub Test_()
    Dim ILastrow As Long
    ILastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(ILastrow + 3, 3).Value = Int(Application.Min(Range("D2:D" & ILastrow)) )
End Sub

Comment: Нет, `Int` тоже лишний оператор. См. сообщение выше.

Comment: Понял, сразу не увидел, спасибо!
Sub Test_()
    Dim ILastrow As Long
    ILastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(ILastrow + 3, 3).Value = Application.Min(Range("D2:D" & ILastrow))
End Sub
А в случае медианы писать так: Cells(ILastrow + 3, 3).Value = Application.Median(Range("D2:D" & ILastrow))?